# Android Auto: create map app

Tags: android-auto

According to the official documentation it is possible to create only audio and messaging apps for android auto.

Would it be possible to integrate a map in a view for an android auto app? We can see that waze succeed to do that in their app...

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer?

Comment: Nope. ---------

Comment: You cannot integrate a map using Public SDK. If you partner with Android Auto/Google, then you probably can develop Map application but you cannot develop the navigation apps.

Comment: Does anyone have any information about the process of partnering with Google/Android Auto?